# How to address an alsa "mixer_device" in mpd config for a second sound card?

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, mpd

I run mpd on a system with a built in sound card and a second card that I plugged in via USB.

Adressing the second sound card in the mpd.conf was easy:

change: **device "hw:0:0"** to  **device "hw:1"**

This works fine so far, what's missing though is the volume control. How do I adress the mixer device of the USB card in the mpd config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mpdconf.example` says:

```
audio_output {
       type            "alsa"
       name            "My ALSA Device"
#      device          "hw:0,0"        # optional
#      format          "44100:16:2"    # optional
#      mixer_device    "default"       # optional
#      mixer_control   "PCM"           # optional
#      mixer_index     "0"             # optional
}
```

So you'd need `mixer_device "hw:1"`, and maybe a different `mixer_control` if you device's control has another name.

Comment: Way too easy ;) I have set hw:1 for "device" and "mixer_device" now which works fine.